# Data bandwidth usage fees in eos

Tags: nodeos, eosjs

Where is smart contract data like a table stored?
When I use eojs and execute getTableRows for example, are there any fees or limits?

Answer (score 1):

In EOSIO multi-index tables are stored in RAM. And when you use the function of eosjs getTableRows it will simply read that data from RAM and it will not take any cost to execute that function.

Comment: actually i asked the same here and look https://www.reddit.com/r/EOSDev/comments/9pfkcv/eos_smart_contract_table_data_storage/